# initializing a 2D list in python since i dont know the exact dimensions

Tags: python, list

I want to create a python 2D list, but i will not know the ecaxt dimensions that the list has to be initialized while writing the program.
For example i want a list like this

```
edgelist = [[3,5], [2,5], [4,6], ...]
```

The inner list will have two numbers. But the number of inner list will not be known while coding. the numbers will be assigned after initializing through a loop.

My code is :

```
edgelist = []
val = 0
for every_list in req_data:
for temp in range(1,len(every_list)):
    edgelist[val].append(every_list[0])
    edgelist[val].append(every_list[temp])
    val = val+1
```

When `val == 0` the list appends the value. But the next iteration it shows the error as `IndexError: list index out of range`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
edgelist = []
```

It means that `edgelist` is an empty list. So, `edgelist[0]` will not be able to get anything. That is why it is throwing that error. What you should do is

```
edgelist.append([every_list[0], every_list[temp]])
```

This will create a two element list with `every_list[0]` and `every_list[temp]` and add that list to `edgelist`. So, `edgelist` becomes a list of lists or a 2-D list.

Also, if `req_data` already has two element lists, then you can simply do

```
for every_list in req_data:
    edgelist.append(every_list[:])
```

This will create copies of elements in `req_data` and add it directly to `edgelist`. Its better to use list comprehension, like this

```
edgelist = [every_list[:] for every_list in req_data]
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot. I thought , if I initialize in some other way, I can index the list and store numbers. Thank you. This is apt. :)

Comment: @Abinaya Well, it took sometime to understand why you are using the inner loop. Are you really trying to copy lists in `req_data` to `edgelist`?

Comment: Yeah. the req_data has the raw data and am trying to copy it into the edge list, as sufficiently as i need for the rest of my program..